# Connect 4 TB HDD to Intel Q57 Express onboard SATA-II port

Tags: hard-drive, sata, chipset

I'd like to replace my current data hard disk (SATA-II, 2.0 TB) with a new, bigger one. I considered going for a **new 4 TB drive** by Hitachi (SATA-III).

But I'm not sure, if I can use it with my "old" PC (bought in 12/2010), as I want to connect the new HDD to the onboard SATA ports. The mainboard features an **Intel Q57 Express chipset / Intel 5 Series/3400**. The SATA connectors on the mainboard are **SATA-II only**. As far as I know, SATA-III drives are backward compatible to old SATA-II ports (lower speed, but will work at least).

But what about the drive capacity? In 2010 there were no 4 TB HDDs available. Does anybody know, whether the old chipset will work with that large drives?
The currently used 2 TB drives works fine. But what about 4 TB drives?

I use Windows 7 (64 bit) as operating system. OS and drivers are up to date. All available patches are installed.

I **don't want to boot from** the new 4 TB drive. It's only meant as a place to keep user data.

Comment: You won't be able to boot to a 4TB drive.  You can use it as a data drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use it with Windows 7.

Important factors would have been the BIOS (for booting, which you don't want) and the OS version. If I remember correctly certain older Windows versions will not work with SATA-connected drives beyond 2 TB at all, much like the BIOS/MBR limitation. However, in these cases you can work around it by using a USB-connected casing for the hard-drive.

Comment: Windows 7 won't have this problem.